Proving OLS estimator from two linear models
In a paper I'm reading, the authors try to recover an uncontaminated signal $x$ from two time series of imaging data, $y_1$ and $y_2$, which follow the relationships below:
$y_1$ = $x$ + $z$ + $\eta$
$y_2$ = $A$$z$ + $\xi$
Here, $y_1$ and $y_2$ are $p$ $\times$ $t$ (pixel-by-time) observable signals. $x$ is the true signal the authors try to recover, $z$ is the contamination, and they are uncorrelated. $A$ is a $p$ $\times$ $p$ invertible real matrix that scale $z$ in $y_2$. $\eta$ and $\xi$ are gaussian noise. The authors state that the optimal linear estimator of $x$, in the sense of minimising the mean squared error, is given by:
$\hat{x}$ = $H$$\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix}$,
where $y$ = $\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix}$, $H$ = $\Sigma_{xy}$$\Sigma^{-1}_y$, $\Sigma_{xy}$ = $\mathbb{E}$[$x$$y^{T}$] is the spatial cross-correlation of $x$ and $y$ and $\Sigma_{y}$ = $\mathbb{E}$[$y$$y^{T}$] is the spatial auto-correlation matrix of y.
The authors did not provide steps towards this solution and I'm struggling to derive a proof myself.
